# Multiple AttributeRepository in CAS

Tags: java, spring, ldap, cas, jasig

I'm using CAS (JASIG) 3.5.2 server. I have two LDAP server configured for authentication as **authenticationHandlers**.

Now, I have a requirement to pass user attribute in Validation Response. I am able to configure CAS to return user attributes from one of the LDAP servers with **attributeRepository** bean.

I'm not able to figure out how we can configure CAS to get user attributes from multiple LDAPs.

Following config I have tried.

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.ldap.LdapPersonAttributeDao">
   <property name="contextSource" ref="openldap-contextSource" />
   <property name="requireAllQueryAttributes" value="true" />
   <property name="baseDN" value="dc=myorg,dc=com" />
   <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
      <map>
         <entry key="username" value="uid" />
      </map>
   </property>
   <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
      <map>
         <entry key="sn" value="lastName" />
         <entry key="givenName" value="firstName" />
         <entry key="mail" value="email" />
      </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

This configuration works, if we want single LDAP to get user. If I try to rename the bean name it gives me error in initialization.

Can any one suggest approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two attribute repositories, merge them and call the merged one "attributeRepository"

https://github.com/Jasig/person-directory#mergingpersonattributedaoimpl

Comment: Thanks for reply. I came across this config from JASIG wiki. Looking at bean definition, its making sense this might work. But the issue is I can't find any definitive steps how I can start configure this in JASIG.

Comment: There are no "definitive steps". It's fairly simply. You have two LdapPersonAttributeDao beans. Call one A and call the other B. The declare your attributeRepository bean, that is going to merge A and B per the example. That's it.

Comment: If you want to see a complicated example, see https://github.com/Jasig/uPortal/blob/9897da03a3d33bb43701d41e7112d4bfaba72423/uportal-war/src/main/resources/properties/contexts/personDirectoryContext.xml

Comment: Its still not ringing bells for me. Sadly, might be my lack-of knowledge. What I have is CAS webapp. I can't find where I can place this configuration. Is it going to be in deployerConfigContext.xml or any where else?

Comment: Yes in deployerConfigContext.xml